# How to fix the RecursionError caused by builtins.str from UserString

Tags: python

I want to add a method to `builtins.str` like this, but it causes RecursionError.

```py
import builtins
import unicodedata
from collections import UserString


class String(UserString):
    def isnumber(self):
        try:
            float(self.data)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            pass
        try:
            unicodedata.numeric(self.data)
            return True
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            pass
        return False


builtins.str = String
print(str('0').isnumber())  # True
print('1'.isnumber())  # True
print('-1'.isnumber())  # True
print('0.1'.isnumber())  # True
print('a1'.isnumber())  # False
```

Answer (score 0):

Just **Extending builtin classes in python** can fix it.

But it can't directly `'0'.isnumber()`.

```py
import builtins
import unicodedata


class MyString(str):
    def isnumber(self):
        try:
            float(self)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            pass
        try:
            unicodedata.numeric(self)
            return True
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            pass
        return False


builtins.str = MyString
print(str('0').isnumber())  # True
print(str('1').isnumber())  # True
print(str('-1').isnumber())  # True
print(str('0.1').isnumber())  # True
print(str('a1').isnumber())  # False
```